# Is every simplicial spectrum equivalent to an abelian group simplicial spectrum?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, stable-homotopy

I wonder if every simplicial $S^1$-spectrum stable equivalent to an abelian group simplicial $S^1$-spectrum? It seems that I could use the stable Dold-Kan on the heart and use Postnikov towers?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, the category of simplicial $S^{1}$-spectrum is the stable category with respect to the suspension functor i.e., it is the category of spectra. The category of abelian group simplicial $S^{1}$-spectrum is the stabilization category of the model category of simplicial abelian groups with respect to the "suspension" functor, this category is the category of $HZ$-spactrum i.e the category of spectrum which have the structure of $HZ$-module. The answer to your question (if my interpretation is correct) is no.

Comment: More precisely (if GSM's interpretation of your question is correct, I'm also not 100% sure what your objects are), what goes wrong with your argument sketch is that the objects in the heart are $HZ$-modules, but the way they're glued together (the k-invariants in the postnikov tower) doesn't respect that, i.e. there are non-$HZ$-linear maps between $HZ$-modules.

Comment: @Achim Krause I completely agree with you.